# Wordpress display custom taxonomy column for posts

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom post type (book) and then a custom taxonomy (book_cat) just for this particular post type. It is working fine but if I click on All books page in the dashboard there's no column displaying which categories (book_cat) has a book been assigned to (if any). I need to click on each book to edit and see there.

The register new post type function is:

```
function post_types() {
    register_post_type('book', array(
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'excerpt'),
        'public' => true,
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Books',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Book',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Book',
            'all_items' => 'All Books',
            'singular_name' => 'Book'
        ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-align-center',
        'taxonomies' => array('book_cat')
    ));
}

add_action('init', 'post_types');
```

And the taxonomy is:

```
function books_init() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Books Cat', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Book Cat', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Book Cat' ),
    'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Book Cat' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Book Cats' ),
    'parent_item' => null,
    'parent_item_colon' => null,
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit BCat' ),
    'update_item' => __( 'Update BCat' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New BCat' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New BCat Name' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate BCats with commas' ),
    'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove Bcats' ),
    'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used Bcats' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Book Cats' ),
  );
    // create a new taxonomy
    register_taxonomy(
        'book_cat',
        'book',
        array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'bcat' ),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'books_init' );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add show_admin_column as follow:

```
// create a new taxonomy
register_taxonomy(
    'book_cat',
    'book',

    array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'bcat' ),
        'show_admin_column' => true,

    )
);
}
add_action( 'init', 'books_init' );
```

Comment: Thanks. That's it.